# Problem with Rails Model Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have got 3 models, but the association is a little tricky.

First i've got Users, and for 2 different types of users i have 2 different profile models which are Pteacher and Pstudent.

The thing is also every Pteacher has 1 Pstudent.

So i made the models like this;

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :uname
  has_many :pteachers
  has_many :pstudents
end


class Pteacher < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :pstudent
    belongs_to :user
end

class Pstudent < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_one :pteacher
    belongs_to :user
end
```

And now, if i go through first selecting the User than selecting Pteacher than selecting Pstudent like User.pteacher.pstudent, it gives me No Method error.

BUT

If i select Pteacher directly, than i can select Pstudent with Pteacher.pstudent.

The problem is i want to go through `User=>Pteacher=>Pstudent`

Is there a way to achieve this?

By the way, i find out that i cannot reach any of Pteacher's methods if i create it from User. For example, if i write to Rails Console;

```
user = User.first #Which is a teacher
user.pteachers #This line gives me all the info about that users pteacher
#now funny part
pt = user.pteacher #this works too as now i have pt as a Pteacher which have all the data i want
pt.id #fails???
pt.name #fails???
pt.pstudent #fails???
pt #writes all info about pteacher which has id and name
```

Comment: has_many should be plural here shouldn't it?  What happens if you do just User.pteacher ?

Comment: it seems working. The thing is some of the users are teachers some of them are students. So if the user is a student than User.pteacher returns an empty array, but if the user is a teacher than User.pteacher returns its profile

Comment: The main problem if i select User first, than Pteacher rest fails. But if i don't touch to User, directly select Pteacher, than it works. Damn rails!

Comment: The weird thing to me is that a User has_many :pteacher, but you are describing the relationship as if it has_one :pteacher...

Comment: @Beerlington, sorry i rewrote the code here and i usually forgot to pluralize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it ! :D

The problem was when i ask for User.Pteachers.Pstudent, there is not 1 Pteacher actually it is a Pteachers array. So User.Pteacher.first.Pstudent solved it.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You want the change the relationship from has_one to belongs_to for Pteacher. Try it out and see.

```
class Pstudent < ActiveRecord::Base 
    belongs_to :pteacher
    belongs_to :user
end
```

And also, retrieve the pteacher as so:

```
user = User.first # Which is a teacher
pt = user.pteachers.first # retrieving first teacher from list
p pt # prints out attributes of pt
```

Comment: nope, thanks anyway. By the way as i mentioned, it is not about relationships between my models, it should be something about rails, because i cannot even do User.Pteacher.id

Comment: It's definitely something with your code, not the framework. It would be helpful if you post the output rather than saying "it fails".